# Deep learning in Apollo Client, GraphQL, Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-client

I wanted to develop a full stack application with React Redux,Node,Mongo DB with the combination of GraphQL and appollo client..
And I am very new to GraphQl, Apollo Client and Mongo DB, Mongoose..

Can anyone redirect me to study those technologies... particularly deep study in Apollo Client with easily understandable websites..

Thanks

Comment: Check this out, https://www.howtographql.com/

Comment: thanks!

And another question, while using graphql and appollo client with react-redux, I can see in the internet, at this point redux usage is optional.
But I need to clarify which one is better, whether graphql, appolo and react redux combinaton or graphql,appolo and react combinaton...
Which one is better ?

Comment: No one is better than another, you should pick whichever is convenient for your project. If you're starting from scratch and requirements allow use both, Apollo stack it's a great choice!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some source code about `apollo`(client, server), `graphql`, combine with `react`, `Angular 6` and `express`:

https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-server-express-starter

https://github.com/mrdulin/angular-apollo-starter

https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql

https://github.com/mrdulin/nodejs-graphql

You can take a look.

From `apollo 2.0`, it implements in-memory cache by itself. There is no need add extra state manager lib like `redux`. You should use `apollo-link-state`.